# encoding DataGridView column names

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encoding, utf-8, datagridview

I have a problem with encoding in my app. My MySQL database is encoded in UTF-8 and all records are displayed well in DataGridView, but I can't rename DataGridView columns on polish names.

My select: `"SELECT ZAMOWIENIA.id_zamowienia AS 'ID zamówienia', KLIENCI.login AS 'Login', KLIENCI.imie AS 'Imię', ..."` which later is displayed in DataGridView.

`SET NAMES 'utf8'` works only for `ó` but `ę` is `e` etc.

I tried to add `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; SET collation_connection = utf8_polish_ci;` but it doesn't work for column names.

Comment: I found a solution: `DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText = "XXX"`